# cryptsetup 2.3.4 rpm for CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, disk-encryption

I have been searching for `cryptsetup` 2.3.4 as I want to use `--perf-no_read_workqueue`.

According to the [release note](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v2.3/v2.3.4-ReleaseNotes), the option is newly added in 2.3.4.

However, my CentOS 7's official repository only has 2.0.3.  I tried to rebuild 2.3.4 myself.  However, it has many dependencies that require newer versions of some libraries and expects header files and libraries in different locations, etc.

Anyone knows which repos provides `cryptsetup` 2.3.4?